# How to get the highest numerical value in an array in python

Tags: python

I'm a total novice in python and coding but I'm trying to use a loop on my array to get the highest numerical value in my array I don't even know where to begin so any help is greatly appreciated. So far all I can think to do is

for x in data:
    if x > Members

and that's all I got I don't know what to do next at all so any input will help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in a loop, you’ll have to compare each x to the largest value seen so far.

For example:

```
highest=None
for x in data:
  if (highest is None) or (x > highest):
    highest = x
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a built-in function:

`max(data)`

If you're doing this as a thought experiment, you can use a loop like so:

```
m = -1e309  # negative infinity
for i in data:
  if i > m:
    m = i

print(m)
```

Comment: I prefer `float('-inf')` for negative infinity.

Comment: @darksky fewer characters, and -1e309 is far nerdier 8)

Comment: I don’t know if it’s fewer characters, you had to put a comment in front of it to explain what it is :)

Comment: @darksky ha, touche